# Select the first row that meets a condition + 1 row above

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a SQL query to return the following results:
[Rows returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWjKx.png)

However, I need to further 'filter' it down to only the rows highlighted in yellow, because I want the first row that has param_id = 'update_flag' AND param_val = '1'. I also need the row above that, because I need to retrieve the param_val value (202017) that corresponds to param_id = 'period_from' for the same Order Number (156 in this example).

This is my code, I'm getting data from 2 different tables:

```
SELECT
report1.orderno AS t1_orderno,
report2.orderno AS t2_orderno,
report1.report_name AS t1_reportname,
report2.report_name AS t2_reportname,
report1.variant,
report1.status,
report1.client,
report2.param_id,
report2.param_val 
FROM report1 
INNER JOIN
  report2 
  ON report1.orderno = report2.orderno 
  AND report2.param_id IN 
  (
     'period_from',
     'update_flag'
  )
  AND report1.report_name = 'PR28' 
  AND report1.variant = '20' 
  AND report1.status = 'T' 
  AND report1.client = '10' 
ORDER BY
  report1.orderno DESC
```

Thanks for any help in advance, it's doing my head in!

Comment: Have you looked into the analytic functions like `lag`?

Comment: Thank you Ramin, I'll look into that function!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH num_row AS (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY report1.orderno DESC) as nom,
  report1.orderno AS t1_orderno,
  report2.orderno AS t2_orderno,
  report1.report_name AS t1_reportname,
  report2.report_name AS t2_reportname,
  report1.variant,
  report1.status,
  report1.client,
  report2.param_id,
  report2.param_val 
FROM report1 
INNER JOIN
  report2 
  ON report1.orderno = report2.orderno 
  AND report2.param_id IN (
   'period_from',
   'update_flag'
  )
  AND report1.report_name = 'PR28' 
  AND report1.variant = '20' 
  AND report1.status = 'T' 
  AND report1.client = '10' 
)
SELECT * FROM num_row
WHERE nom BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Comment: Hi, I think that works for MySQL? I'm in MSSQL. I think it would not work either because TOP returns just the first 2 rows without checking for my condition (param_id = 'update_flag' AND param_val = '1').

Comment: Sorry for my inattentiveness. I'm update answer text.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm sorry it did not work. It says illegal SQL. Also, what numbers should I be using for "WHERE nom BETWEEN (n - m) AND n" in my case? I used 1 and 10 but I don't understand how it works in my example.

Comment: Yes, i make mistake in last row of sql. Code updated